# Configure function with HAC matrix in R

Tags: r

Here is an example of how to configure a function that estimates robust standard errors with `sandwich` package in R

```
library("sandwich")
se.robust <- function(model.object) {
  model.fit <- vcovHC(model.object, type = "HC")
  out <- sqrt(diag(model.fit))
  return(out)
}
```

In order to deal with heteroscedasticity and AR(1) process it would be necessary to use the HAC matrix, `vcovHAC`.

How can I configure this function to work with the HAC matrix? Specifically, what should I put in the *out* line to make the `vcovHAC` configuration work properly? Since now I'm dealing with a full matrix and not only the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still want diagonal elements of the variance covariance matrix, because they are variance. So as long as you have something like `vcovHAC(model.object)`, it is fine:

```
library("sandwich")
se.robust <- function(model.object) {
  model.fit <- vcovHAC(model.object)
  out <- sqrt(diag(model.fit))
  return(out)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that the treatment was more complex